# What is the original meaning of 匈 (besides "chest/breast/thorax")?

Tags: meaning, characters, etymology, history, glyph-origin

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiongnu#Ethno-linguistics) on the 匈奴 gives a literal translation as '`fierce slaves`'.

Did 匈 mean '`fierce`' in former times? What is the etymology of this character?

Comment: FYI, `胸` means `chest/breast/thorax`, not `匈`.

Comment: @ThomasHsieh Check Pleco or http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8C%88
I hope you know the story behind 永 and 泳 to understand why 匈 means thorax/chest/breast.

Comment: I don't really think this interpretation listed on WP is correct. "奴" could mean "lowly people", but not necessarily literally "slave" in this context. It could also just be a pure transliteration. Not to mention "匈" is also more likely a transliteration of the sound instead of "fierce", because "fierce" is "凶"

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Thanks for the lesson! I have almost no knowledge on Chinese character etymology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`匈` is the ancient character of `胸`, means `chest/breast`. And I can't find any other original meaning of it besides this.

> “胸”的古字 [bosom;chest]
>   匈,膺也。——《说文》。字亦作胷、作胸

According to the explanation of `胸`, it's a later character for `匈`.

> 从肉,匈声。本作“匈”,胸是后起字。

`匈奴` is just the transliteration from the name of an ancient nationality in North China, has nothing to do with `fierce slaves`.

Reference:
[匈的解释](http://www.zdic.net/z/16/xs/5308.htm)
[胸的解释](http://www.zdic.net/z/22/xs/80F8.htm)
[孙健：说说“匈奴”这个词的起源](http://news.guoxue.com/article.php?articleid=18246)

Comment: Thanks for the 匈 ~ 胸 etymology. I hope other people, like @Thomas Hsieh can also understand this phenomenon.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster BTW, back to your question, I can't find any other original meaning of it.

Answer (score 1):

凶 seems to mean fierce. http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/51F6.htm
勹 means wrap.

'wrap up something fierce' Your raging spirit??